# private selector to bring ios app to foreground

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, foreground

I know that regular iOS app shouldn't get itself into suspended, and shouldn't wake itself from background. Suspension and activation should be operated by user. However, I am making myself an app to wake up from Microsoft Band tile open event and then make phone call. I got the tile open event already. And inside the event I tried

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel:8001234567")!)
```

However, no outgoing call made. I figure it's because the app is still in background. Therefore, I wonder if there is private selector to bring it to foreground, like this pushing it to background.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector("suspend")
```

if anyone suggests

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] launchApplicationWithIdentifier:@"" suspended:NO];
```

please tell me how to set it up in a swift project!